# Как заменить старый объект на новый?

Tags: c#

Имеется некий класс с полем ссылочного типа (`Fitting fit`). Создаю экземпляр `fit = new Fitting` (конструктор) и работаю с ним. Затем, мне нужно, не выходя из программы, создать другой экземпляр моего `fit`?, используя другой конструктор или изменив параметры прежнего.

Следует ли форсировано уничтожать старый экземпляр, как это я бы делал в С++ с помощью деструктора и `delete`?

Comment: наверное в общем случае сборщик сам справится

Comment: Покажите код того как вы собираетесь уничтожить старый экземпляр

Comment: @ Андрей NOP я пока не умею этого делать, но если надо, научусь как-нибудь. А, главное, не знаю нужно ли.

Comment: _Память_ освободит сборщик мусора. А вот об освобождении _ресурсов_ нужно позаботиться самому: если ваш класс реализует интерфейс `IDisposable`, то вызовите метод `Dispose`.

Comment: Оператора `delete` в C# нет. Деструкторов тоже нет. Есть финализаторы, но это совсем другое.